# setTimeout and setInterval's second param is required? if not, what is the default value?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

```
setTimeout(function(){...}, 100);
```

my question is can I remove `100` completely? If yes, what is the default value `setTimeout` receive in all modern browsers?

I had researched in 4 documents but can't find any for my question

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) says it is required but [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) is not required and default value is 0, [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536753(v=vs.85).aspx) and [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/timers.html) have nothing :)

Comment: I believe it will cast `undefined` to 0.

Comment: Why would you *want* to remove it completely? It defines how often the function should be called.

Comment: @Scott sometimes I just want to fix the problem of js execution that don't run if a function is called directly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Answer (score 2):

As per the **non normative** W3C Recommendation (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout)

> handle = window.setTimeout( handler [, timeout [, arguments... ] ] )
>
> handle = window.setInterval( handler [, timeout [, arguments... ] ] )

The 2nd argument (timeout) is optional and

> 5. Let timeout be the second method argument, or zero if the argument was omitted.

the default value is 0.

---

However do note that

> Note: Timers can be nested; **after five such nested timers**, however,
> the interval is forced to be at least four milliseconds.